# Add default class and class from scope in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add two classes in angular. One is always the same and one is retrieved by the scope.

I attempted this:

```
<label class="checkbox" ng-switch-when="checkbox" ng-class="{{field.name}}">
<input
    name="{{field.key}}"
    type="checkbox"
    value="Option 1"
    ng-model="$storage[field.key]"
>
    {{field.label}}
</label>
```

It generated two-class attributes in the DOM.

This:

```
<label ng-switch-when="checkbox" ng-class="{{field.name}} checkbox">
<input
    name="{{field.key}}"
    type="checkbox"
    value="Option 1"
    ng-model="$storage[field.key]"
>
    {{field.label}}
</label>
```

didn't add anything to the class-attribute at all

Comment: `ng-class="['checkbox', field.name]"`

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple example on plunker for you here (http://plnkr.co/edit/H7JstMuvHSlwPSy3raPO?p=preview). The core of the example is:

```
<div ng-class="{red: showRed, bold: showBold}">Hello Plunker!</div>
```

To make this example work, you need to define two booleans "showRed" and "showBold" in your controller. Its very simple but the controller code looks like:

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.showRed = true;
  $scope.showBold = true;
});
```

When you toggle these boolean values true/false, the classes will toggle on and off the element. In order to make this easy to see, I added two buttons to the example so you can toggle without changing code. Hope this helps you out. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-class` expects an expression that evaluates to a string, an array or a map. Btw. You don't need `{{` because the whole string already is an expression.

Your second expression cannot be evaluated. It's like a line in JavaScript `field.name checkbox` - that's not valid code. `field.name + ' checkbox'` would be. You could use that.

An array would definitely be easier to use if you had more dynamic classes:

`[field.name, someOtherVariable, 'checkbox']`.